# Logging COM calls with OllyDBG

Tags: com

I want to look at directx calls with ollydbg, and log and decode all parameters. Somebody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you absolutely need to use OllyDbg for this, you really should use something like http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor which has DirectX call logging and decoding built-in:

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

And if you seriously do need to use OllyDbg for this, you should explain why.

Comment: No reason other than being familiar with olly. And I actually tried this month ago, didn't worked for me for some reason. I guess it's time to try again, this time reading manuals.